# Slideshow image blows up on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, carousel

I just added a slider and carousel to my Volusion website homepage.
However, when I went to the page, the first carousel image would blow up to a huge size (original size is only 180 x 270) and flash twice. So I looked through the code and removed a line:

```
<script src="/v/vspfiles/templates/192/homepage/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Because I thought maybe it's trying to load the javascript twice or something.

After I did this, the carousel image still blows up to a huge size on load, but only once.

Here is the page where it is happening on: http://www.wallsrepublic.com

All of the relevant code I have on my home page is below:

```
 <script src="/v/vspfiles/templates/192/homepage/js/mobilyslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/v/vspfiles/templates/192/homepage/js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For the main slider:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/v/slider/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/v/Slider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>`

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).load(function() {
$(".flexslider").flexslider();
});


$(window).load(function() {
  $(".flexslider").flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    minItems: 2,
    maxItems: 4
  });
});
</script>

<div class="flexslider" style="width:auto;overflow:hidden;">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
<a href='http://www.wallsrepublic.com/home-wallpapers-online-s/1814.htm' ><img alt='Home Wallpaper' src="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/v/vspfiles/slider/slide1.jpg" height='452' width='975' border='0' /></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href='http://www.wallsrepublic.com/home-wallpapers-online-s/1814.htm'><img alt='Wallpaper Murals' src="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/v/vspfiles/slider/slide2-1.jpg" height='452' width='975' border='0' /></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href='http://www.wallsrepublic.com/home-wallpapers-online-s/1814.htm'><img alt='Wallpaper Sale' src="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/v/vspfiles/slider/slide3.jpg" height='452' width='975' border='0' /></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

For the problematic carousel:

```
    <script src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/amazingcarousel.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/initcarousel-1.css">
    <script src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/initcarousel-1.js"></script>


<!-- PRODUCT CAROUSEL -->
<div id="amazingcarousel-container-1">
    <div id="amazingcarousel-1" style="display:block;position:relative;width:100%;max-width:900px;margin:0px auto 0px;">
        <div class="amazingcarousel-list-container">
            <ul class="amazingcarousel-list">
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/gold-damask-wallpaper-p/r2067-parent.htm" title="GOLD DAMASK   " ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/1.png"  alt="GOLD DAMASK   " /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">GOLD DAMASK  </div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$159 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/grey-overlay-wallpaper-p/s43712-parent.htm" title="GREY OVERLAY    " ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/2.png"  alt="GREY OVERLAY  " /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">GREY OVERLAY </div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$89 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/black-white-dogstooth-wallpaper-p/r2542-parent.htm" title="BLACK & WHITE DOGSTOOTH " ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/3.png"  alt="BLACK & WHITE DOGSTOOTH   " /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">BLACK & WHITE DOGSTOOTH  </div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$119 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/brown-fawn-wallpaper-p/r2339-parent.htm" title="BROWN FAWN " ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/4.png"  alt="BROWN FAWN    " /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">BROWN FAWN   </div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$139 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/R1373-p/r1373-parent.htm" title="SERENITY SAND" ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/5.png"  alt="SERENITY SAND" /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">SERENITY SAND</div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$149 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/taupe-stone-modern-residential-wallpaper-R1875-p/r1875-parent.htm" title="BLOCK-STONE GREY" ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/6.png"  alt="BLOCK-STONE GREY" /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">BLOCK-STONE GREY</div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$79 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/marsala-running-brick-wallpaper-p/r2587-parent.htm" title="MARSALA RUNNING BRICK" ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/7.png"  alt="MARSALA RUNNING BRICK" /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">MARSALA RUNNING BRICK</div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$79 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/geometric-gold-residential-wallpaper-R1861-p/r1861-parent.htm" title="TIA GOLD" ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/8.png"  alt="TIA GOLD" /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">TIA GOLD</div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$119 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/antique-world-map-mural-p/m9167-parent.htm" title="ANTIQUE WORLD MAP MURAL" ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/9.png"  alt="ANTIQUE WORLD MAP MURAL" /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">ANTIQUE WORLD MAP MURAL</div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$399 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/blue-wood-pattern-residential-wallpaper-R1878-p/r1878-parent.htm" title="BRUSHED WOOD BLUE" ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/10.png"  alt="BRUSHED WOOD BLUE" /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">BRUSHED WOOD BLUE</div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$89 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/black-and-white-lattice-wallpaper-p/r2548-parent.htm" title="BLACK & WHITE LATTICE" ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/11.png"  alt="BLACK & WHITE LATTICE" /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">BLACK & WHITE LATTICE</div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$119 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
<div class="amazingcarousel-image"><a href="http://www.wallsrepublic.com/gold-victorian-wallpaper-p/s43751-parent.htm" title="GOLD VICTORIAN" ><img src="http://wallsrepublic.com/v/carousel/12.png"  alt="GOLD VICTORIAN" /></a></div>
<div class="amazingcarousel-text">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">GOLD VICTORIAN</div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-description">$149 USD</div>
</div>                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="amazingcarousel-prev"></div>
            <div class="amazingcarousel-next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="amazingcarousel-nav"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had the javascript and css files in my template header before, but then the slideshows did not work so I had to move them to be directly on the home page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: instead of window.load. Try using jquery's dom ready. $(document ).ready(function() {});

Comment: @dowomenfart didn't work, it's still acting the same

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(".flexslider").flexslider();
});
```

Try to remove those lines, you are calling the slider 2 times for the same class.

Comment: When I removed these lines it made my slider look really awful and stop working

Comment: That's wired, have you try to load the js in bottom of page instead?

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately it's still not fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an issue with Flexslider that's causing this.

As far as I can tell, it is caused by the wallpaper swatch displaying at 100% width before the amazing carousel plugin kicks in and wraps the image to a smaller width.

Try adding this to your stylesheet

```
.amazingcarousel-item {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
```

This will give the carousel item a width by default, which in turn causes the image inside it to be a smaller width.

Comment: Alright, now instead of the image being blown up, it shows all of the products at once as if the carousel isn't working properly, then goes back to normal. I still think this looks better than the blown up image, but it's still not showing properly.